# How to use Cassandra Map type in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra

I have created the table in the keyspace like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myks.users (user_id text, device_ids map<text,text>);

I'm trying to insert the below data using `spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra` library in Spring boot

{
    "userId" : "krishna",
    "deviceIds": {
        "DeviceId_0": "TYNLSANID7",
        "DeviceId_1": "julasjasd8",
        "DeviceId_2": "iu89074hasd",
        "DeviceId_3": "Lenovo hjyas|asdqnkasd"
    }
}
```

and below is the entity class

```
@Column("user_id")
@CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TEXT)
private String userId;

@Column("device_ids")
@CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.MAP)
private Map<String, String> deviceIds= new HashMap<>();
```

I'm getting the below exception when inserting the data into table

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Expected [2] type arguments for property ['deviceIds'] of type ['interface java.util.Map'] in entity [com.kri.entity.Users]; actual was [0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As specified in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/mapping/CassandraType.html#typeArguments--) you should provide the `typeArguments` property in the annotation definition when you are working with `Collection`, and in specific for `Map` data type you should provide two `DataType Name` properties, one for the key and one for the value resipectively:

```
@CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.MAP,typeArguments = { DataType.Name.TEXT,DataType.Name.TEXT}
```